# How to exclude createdAT and updatedAt from ALL Queries in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Node 14 and Sequelize modeling an existing Postgres DB.

The TAbles already created do not have createdAt neighter updatedAt Colums so I would like to instruct my Sequelize  to NEVER try Select, Insert or Update those Atribbutes.

So I tried

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize (
  config.database, 
  config.username, 
  config.password, 
  config.params,
  { define: {
     defaultScope: {
      attributes: { exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt'] }
     },
     timestamps: false 
  }
})
```

But even this way ... my `findAll()` insist to select `createdAt` and `updatedAt`

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you considered doing this on the Model level?

Comment: Yes ... in fact in model works ... but is not a GLOBAL WAY to do that ? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, what you have is supposed to work, but as we know programming can be funny sometimes. :(

Consider trying the following options:

- Using the [`beforeFind`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v6/lib/hooks.js#L31) hook method
- Adding scopes to exclude `createdAt` & `updatedAt` attributes just as taught in [this guide](https://bcostabatista.medium.com/sequelize-exclude-fields-from-query-result-48043ea0d499)

#### Option one example

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize (
  config.database, 
  config.username, 
  config.password, 
  config.params,
  { 
    define: {
      hooks: {
        beforeFind: (model) => {
           model.attributes = {}
           models.attributes.exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt']
        }
      },
      timestamps: false 
  }
})
```

#### Option two example

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize (
  config.database, 
  config.username, 
  config.password, 
  config.params,
  { define: {
     scopes: {
      excludeCreatedAtUpdateAt: {
        attributes: { exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt'] }
      }
     },
     timestamps: false 
  }
})

// Then use it when making your queries like this
const data = await Model.scope('excludeCreatedAtUpdateAt').findAll(...)
```